# how to get an array of objects from sql query

Tags: php, mysql

My code is

```
$sql = 'select * from table;' $res = $connection->query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res){'tackle output'};
```

to get an object

```
while($row = $res->fetch_object()){'tackle output'};
```

**Question:** what do I have to do to get an array of objects, so my output is thus

```
$data[$row[0]]= fetch_object();
```

Comment: please try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: `fecth_assoc` is an array. `$row['fieldName']`, i need an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like

```
$data = array();
while($row = $res->fetch_object()){
      $data[$row->id] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
$data = array();
while($row = $res->fetch_object()){
      $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I need a `rec id` to be the `array index`. For use in, `if(isset($data[$id})){do something}`

Comment: put it like $data[$row->id] = $row;

Comment: @bluepinto you are welcome, i have answered your question, if its helpful to you please fill free to accept and UV answer

Answer (score 0):

may you want to fetch all 
you can do this by 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php